# The appearance of viewer.isolate() in Forge Viewer v7 is different from v6, is it possible to get v6 appearance?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I recently updated the code to Forge viewer v7 and noticed that the transparency appearance when applying viewer.isolate() is different in v7, compared to v6.  v6 looks like this:

[viewer.isolate() appearance in Forge viewer v6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kv2I.png)

Where as in v7, it looks like this:

[viewer.isolate() appearance in v7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7HhD.png)

with a grey shading for the transparent elements.  I see we can use viewer.setLightPreset() to change the environment appearance, but there doesn't seem to have one setting that can get the v6 appearance.  Is there some other setting I can apply in the code to get the v6 look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try toggle the ghosting brightness setting and see if you can get the desired outcome:

```
NOP_VIEWER.impl.setGhostingBrightness(true/false);
NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true)
```

If the issue persists pls upload the model file to Dropbox/GDrive/weTransder etc and drop the link to forge.help at autodesk.com so we can look into it.

Comment: Thanks!  Helps a lot with a lighter shading.